# Put text side by side with CSS

Tags: html, css

I wan to make a letter template with html like image below where nama siswa will be filled from database and as we see the colon always in same line.

[image]

i have tried this

```
<div class="row">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Kelas :</dt><dd>X TIK 1</dd>
        <dt>Wali Kelas :</dt><dd>Mitra Mulyani</dd>
        <dt>Jumlah Siswa :</dt><dd>0</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

and using boostrap css but not suit my need.
The result with bootstrap is like this
[image]
how to do that with css?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far to achieve this and what problem(s) you are facing in it?

Comment: please add you code so we can check what is going wrong. thanks

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto I have updated your code to get desired display. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used flex box to achieve it. thanks

```css
.d-flex p{
width:110px}

.d-flex{
display:flex
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <p>Kelas </p>
      <p>:X TIK 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <p>Wali Kelas </p>
      <p>:Mitra Mulyani</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <p>Jumlah Siswa </p>
      <p>:0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="row">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>Kelas</td>
       <td>:</td>
       <td>X TIK 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Wali Kelas</td>
       <td>:</td>
       <td>Mitra Mulyani</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Jumlah Siswa</td>
       <td>:</td>
       <td>0</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code.

```
td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td:last-child {
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Bootstrap 3, you can use `definition lists` for displaying your data. Reference Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#horizontal-description

Below is your updated code. You will need to view in full page to view the desired result.

```css
.dl-horizontal dt::after {
  content: ":";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 3px
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 170px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Kelas</dt>
  <dd>X TIK 1</dd>
  <dt>Wali Kelas</dt>
  <dd>Mitra Mulyani</dd>
  <dt>Jumlah Siswa</dt>
  <dd>0</dd>  
</dl>
```

If you need the horizontal display in mobile view also, you can update custom CSS:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```